# Redis Connection Failure error occurs when getting application.properties from config-server

Tags: git, spring-boot, redis, spring-cloud-config, application.properties

I have a Redis service running in localhost:6379 and the spring-boot microservice connects to this redis service by reading the hostname and port from the application.properties file.

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    /**
    * redis host.
    */
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    /**
     * redis port.
     */
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;


    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConf);
}
```

In the application.properties file, the properties given are -

```
spring.redis.host=localhost 
spring.redis.port=6379
```

This works *Perfectly* when i am running the microservice in default profile that is it uses the default application.properties from the `/src/main/resources` folder.

Now the Challenge I am facing is that, when i run the microservice in test profile, it has to fetch the properties file from the config-server which clones it from a github repo.

In this scenario, the redis service is showing an error like this

> [ERROR][2019-05-30 15:48:33,761][pool-1-thread-4|org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer:handleSubscriptionException:651] Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms

This error occurs only when i am getting the properties file from the config-service.

The application-test.properties in the github repo is also having the correct redis configurations.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after lot of debugging i found out what was going wrong. It was due to the unwanted space at the end of `spring.redis.host=localhost` that was causing this issue.

Comment: Yes ,Same problem happened to me also.I followd your answer and it's working fine now.I cleared the unwanted space at the end of **spring.redis.host=localhost** , and in my case **localhost** were in double quotes.I removed that also.